# ActiveMQ Artemis - address auto deletion

Tags: activemq-artemis

1) I have defined an address "myAddress" in the file broker.xml:

```xml
<addresses>
   ...
   <address name="myAddress">
      <multicast/>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

2) I also have disabled the auto-delete-addresses (which does not seem necessary as per my use case, because my address is not auto-created)

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
   ...
   <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>         
</address-setting>
```

As per my understanding, this address is not auto created, and this address does not get auto-deleted by Artemis, as expected.

But, once I have one or more consumers connected to a queue matching this address, and when those consumers all leave, then the address is deleted:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] deleting auto-created address "myAddress."
```

Why is that ? I don't understand why:

1. this address is considered as auto-created
2. this address is still deleted despite the auto-delete-addresses flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're hitting the bug [ARTEMIS-2391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2391).

You can work-around the issue by setting this in broker.xml:

```xml
<address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>
```

Comment: Thank you Justin, I was not sure that was bug, I should have looked into the issue tracker.